# batch read file name as a variable and then use the variable in another batch process

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a simple .txt file (myfile.txt) containing the names of the 300+ files in the same directory. Each line contains the name of one file and each file name has spaces - something like:

```
file number one.txt
file number two.txt
file number three.txt
....
file number three hundred and twenty five.txt
```

I want to batch process each file without hard coding every file name in my main batch script (process.bat).

My process.bat simply opens and processes a file (currently hard coded) with a command-line app and then saves the processed file to a different directory but maintains the original file name.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansionstart 
start prooftool -c "file number one.txt" "/processed/file number one.txt"
```

I somehow need to dynamically replace "file number one.txt" with a variable (i.e. the file name) from myfile.txt and then write the processed data to a new file named exactly the same as the original file but in a folder called  "processed".

To read the file names from mytext.txt I tried:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do [process.bat] %%A
```

but process.bat has nothing to process.

I have looked up how to read lines from a text file into variables and I think maybe the spaces in the file names are causing problems!?

I don't understand where the variables are stored (I presume in memory?) also, how do I call a variable to be processed by my process.bat script (file names are currently hard coded) and then how to call the next variable etc so that it loops through and processes all the files in the directory.

Thanks for your time and patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do [process.bat] "%%A"
```

quoting the `metavariable` makes the entire string, including the spaces, a single token. Since you haven't shown us `process.bat`, we're guessing, sadly.

In your `process.bat` file, you'd need

```
start "some windowtitle" prooftool -c "%~1" "\processed\%~1"
```

`start` uses the first quoted string as a window-title; you can make this an empty string if you wish, but don't omit it.

`"%~1"` means `quote (the-first-parameter-stripped-of-quotes)`.

Path separators in winbatch are `\` . `/` is used to indicate switches. Sometimes, but not always, `/` is translated to `\` - best to use the correct character.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but no luck. I've expanded my description a little to include the process.bat

Comment: This process.bat nearly works


@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do start "" prooftool -c "%%A" "C:\Users\Per\Desktop\batch\processed\%%A.txt"


but only the first few files are processed and saved. I think it's because it has trouble keeping up with writing the processed files to disk - is there any way to slow it down other than splitting the myfile.txt into smaller lists?

In addition to the correctly processed files I get some 0kb files saved and it opens lots of cmd windows but then it seems to lockup and I have to reboot

Comment: I think reading and writing to the same drive was the bottleneck. Changing the write directory to another drive worked and it now processes all files. many thanks for your help Magoo!